# Is yoga an independent philosophy as classified in shad-darshan? or was it later incorporated in Tantra? or is it a part of tantra itself?

Tags: history, philosophy, yoga, tantra

There is a separate school in Āstika tradition of Sanatana dharma as "Yoga". Also, the tantrik texts consists a section as Yoga itself. So how does the yoga as mentioned in Shad-Darshana differs from the one mentioned in Tantrik texts, both in terms of practise and philosophy? I once happen to see Swami Niranjanananda Saraswati of Bihar Yoga say "Tantra is the father of Yoga." So how did this system of Yoga originate in Tantra per se.

Comment: Yoga that is practical indeed comes from Tantras (and few other Yogic scriptures like Shiva Samhita etc.) .. So, what Swamiji says is right .. Tantras also contain the concepts of Kundali Yoga which is not found in Patanjali Sutras.. Also, Patanajali Sutras are philosophical in nature (the text itself is a Darshana) .. There is hardly anyone who "practices Yoga" by following them ..The text's practical utility is thus almost nil.